# Can a file path be invalid UTF-8?

Tags: filenames, unicode

Title says it all: if I have the bytes of a file path and I try to decode them as UTF-8 is it possible that the operation will fail (i.e. the bytes of a valid unix file path can be invalid UTF-8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, perfectly. The file path/name for native Linux filesystems can contain any binary data aside from `NULL` and `/`.

```bsh
touch "$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1)"
```

will get you there. The command may fail since it doesn't sanitize anything - you may need to run it several times for good measure.

Comment: Please don't let beginners create files named like `*` or `-` they'll try to delete later!

Comment: LMAO :-) ......

Answer (score 5):

**In addition to Artem S. Tashkinov's answer:**

A common reason to stumble over invalid UTF-8 sequences within filenames: They've been created under a different locale setting. And yes: It's not uncommon to find systems still running with an ISO-8859 character set encoding. Not to mention the myriads of different character sets used on PCs and MACs all over the world...

The following example shows two files with the same name *Überraschung* (german for *surprise*) in the same directory. One file was created with `LANG=en_us.UTF-8`, the other one with `LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-15`:

when listed using the UTF-8 encoding:

```
    $ ls -lt
    total 0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 ktf ktf 0 Sep  6 12:01 ''$'\334''berraschung'
    -rw-r--r-- 1 ktf ktf 0 Sep  6 12:00  Überraschung
```

and when listed using the ISO-8859-15 encoding:

```
    $ ls -lt
    total 0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 ktf ktf 0 Sep  6 12:01  Überraschung
    -rw-r--r-- 1 ktf ktf 0 Sep  6 12:00 'Ã'$'\234''berraschung'
```

**Hint:** To properly switch between character sets you have to change **both** of the following settings:

1. The setting of the environment variable `LANG` within the UNIX/Linux shell. That controls how the UNIX-system interprets and handles the characters.
2. The character encoding of your terminal emulation (e.g. *gnome-term* or *putty*). That controls how the characters are displayed on your screen.